# How do I prevent jquery ui datepicker from populating textfield?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
$( ".datepicker_1" ).datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            minDate: new Date('<?php echo $st_date_sh.' '.$st_month_sh.', '.$st_year_sh?> 00:00:00'),   //line 88
            maxDate: new Date('<?php echo $en_date_sh.' '.$en_month_sh.', '.$en_year_sh?> 12:00:00'),   //line 88           
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/Cal.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            /*beforeShowDay:function(dt){
                return [(dt.getDay()==0)?false:true];
            },*/
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var dt_txt = dateText.replace('-','/');
                dt_txt = dt_txt.replace('-','/');
                var tmp_dt =  new Date(dt_txt);
                if(tmp_dt.getDay()==0)
                {
                    if(confirm("Are you certain you want to assign Sunday delivery date?"))
                    {
                        //$(this).closest("tr").find(".update_quote_row").click();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

        });
```

What I want to do is, if user tries to select a sunday, a confirmation should be shown and the associated textfield would be populated only after the selection has been confirmed. With my code however, no matter if I confirm or cancel, the textfield changes to the selected value, and I need to prevent that. I can't also simply set the input field to blank as because there might be existing values which should not be modified if the user cancels the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea :

1. Assign your datepicker to a div. See 'Display inline' example in http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline
2. onclick of the input field, show the div. Make sure you copy the date (if present) in the input field to the datepicker div before show
3. Then you can select your date accordingly and the date in the input field would not change.
4. After getting your required date, click the submit button and assign the date on the datepicker to the input field and hide the div.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous value of textfield in some variable and work accordingly, like:

```
var prevVal = $.trim( $("input.datepicker_1").val() );
$( ".datepicker_1" ).datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: false,
    ......
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
         var dt_txt = dateText.replace('-','/');
         dt_txt = dt_txt.replace('-','/');
         var tmp_dt =  new Date(dt_txt);
         if(tmp_dt.getDay()==0) {
           if(confirm("Are you certain you wa...")) {
              return true;
           }
           else {
              //show previous value
              $(".datepicker_1").val(prevVal);
           }
          .........
```